# HQL: How to sort list of objects on property of mapped composite element

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, hql

I have an object with a map of components:

```
<class name="Article" table="articles">
 ...
  <map name="i18nData" table="articles_i18n">
      <key column="id" not-null="true"/>
      <map-key column="language" type="string"/>

      <composite-element class="Article$ArticleI18nData">
        <property name="displayName" type="string"/>
      </composite-element>

    </map>      

</class>
```

How would a HQL query look like to retrieve all "article" objects ordered by the 'displayName' property of the mapped component, mapped with a key for e.g. 'EN'?

thanks,
chris

Answer (score 1):

Add an "order-by" attribute to the map element:

```
<map name="i18nData" table="articles_i18n" order-by="name asc">
  ..
</map>
```

Value of the attribute are database column names.

See:

- Hibernate documentation - 6.2. Collection mappings (docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/collections-mapping.html)
- Hibernate documentation - 6.3.1. Sorted collections (docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/collections-advancedmappings.html)

Sorry I'am a new user and not allowed to add real hyperlinks.

Comment: this would only order the map entries of each article but not the order of the article objects itself.